# Inject ChangeTracker into constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I'd like to reuse a concept we had put into place in another project with asp.net core. The registered `IEntityMetadataProvider`s will be called by the `DbContext` before saving an entity with following code:

```
public class SppdContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IEntityMetadataProvider> _entityMetadataProviders;

    public SppdContext(DbContextOptions<SppdContext> options, IEnumerable<IEntityMetadataProvider> entityMetadataProviders) : base(options)
    {
        _entityMetadataProviders = entityMetadataProviders;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        PrepareSaveChanges();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void PrepareSaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        SetModifierMetadataOnChangedEntities();
    }

    private void SetModifierMetadataOnChangedEntities()
    {
        foreach (var entityMetadataProvider in _entityMetadataProviders)
        {
            entityMetadataProvider.SetModifierMetadataOnChangedEntities();
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
public class EntityMetadataProvider : IEntityMetadataProvider
{
    private readonly ChangeTracker _changeTracker;

    public EntityMetadataProvider(ChangeTracker changeTracker)
    {
        _changeTracker = changeTracker;
    }

    public void SetModifierMetadataOnChangedEntities()
    {
        var entriesToSetModifier = _changeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>().Where(e => HasToSetModifierMetadata(e.State)).ToList();

        if (entriesToSetModifier.Count > 0)
        {
            var saveDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            foreach (var entryToSetModifier in entriesToSetModifier)
            {
                SetModifierMetadataProperties(entryToSetModifier, saveDate);
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool HasToSetModifierMetadata(EntityState state)
    {
        return state == EntityState.Added || state == EntityState.Modified;
    }

    private static void SetModifierMetadataProperties(EntityEntry<BaseEntity> entry, DateTime saveDate)
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).CurrentValue = saveDate;
        }
        else
        {
            entry.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).IsModified = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The `DbContext` is being registered like this:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Sppd; Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
services.AddDbContext<SppdContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

With this implementation I get following exception when on `var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SppdContext>();`:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker' while attempting to activate 'SppdDocs.Infrastructure.DbAccess.EntityMetadataProvider'.
```

How can I register `ChangeTracker` so it can be injected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to look for changes in the change tracker of the SppdContext.

You cannot get the changetracker by injection. It is owned by the instance of your context. You should pass the Changetracker when calling the method instead of the constructor.

in the SpddContext class you will get

```
private void SetModifierMetadataOnChangedEntities()
{
    foreach (var entityMetadataProvider in _entityMetadataProviders)
    {
        entityMetadataProvider.SetModifierMetadataOnChangedEntities(ChangeTracker);
    }
}
```

and in the EntityMetaDataProvider:

```
public class EntityMetadataProvider : IEntityMetadataProvider
{

    public EntityMetadataProvider()
    {       
    }

    public void SetModifierMetadataOnChangedEntities(ChangeTracker changeTracker)
    {
        var entriesToSetModifier = changeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>().Where(e => 
HasToSetModifierMetadata(e.State)).ToList();

        if (entriesToSetModifier.Count > 0)
        {
            var saveDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            foreach (var entryToSetModifier in entriesToSetModifier)
            {
                SetModifierMetadataProperties(entryToSetModifier, saveDate);
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: I had also thought about this but preferred to let the IEntityMetadataProvider implementations to decide what they want to use (in the mentioned case, based on the ChangeTracker). If it is not possible to inject the ChangeTracker your suggestion will work fine. Thanks :)